# Popovers and not disappearing keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a popover that has a textfield on it, when I click on the popover background, the keyboard disappears. However when I click around the popover area, the keyboard doesn't disappear.

Is there a way I can get into the delegate that collapses the popover so that I can add the resignfirstresponder command.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! UIPopoverController has a delegate method `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:` in which you can add the resignFirstResponder command.

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [self.someTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can send any view in the view hierarchy above the views that can be first responder the `endEditing:` message.  This is handy if you don't have a reference to the first responder to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can call resign responder methods to the popover dismissal delegate like :

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
                            OR
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController